# How to get Google profile image to Firebase Storage only once at first login?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm trying to save a user to Firebase Ftorage with Google login. I have saved the data, but the problem is each time the same user logs in more than once, the profile image of that Google account gets uploaded.

So I have a lot of identical images. How can I make it so that it will only uploaded only the first time, when the user gets authenticated?

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    let authentication = user.authentication
    let credential = FIRGoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: (authentication?.idToken)!,
                                                      accessToken: (authentication?.accessToken)!)
    SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "Loading...")
    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential) { (userFireBase, error) in
        if error != nil{
            print(error)
        }
        else{

            guard let uid = userFireBase?.uid, let name = user.profile.name, let email = user.profile.email else{
                return
            }

            //  successfully authenticated user

            let imageURL = user.profile.imageURL(withDimension: 120).absoluteString
            let url  = NSURL(string: imageURL) as! URL
            let data = NSData(contentsOf: url)
            let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
           let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("profileImages").child("\(imageName).png")
            let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(data: data! as Data)!)
             storageRef.put(uploadData!, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error)
                return
            }

            if let profileImageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString {
                let values = ["name": name,"email":email,"profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl]
                self.registerUserIntoDatabaseWithUid(uid: uid, values: values as [String : AnyObject])
            }

        })

        }
    }
}

    private func registerUserIntoDatabaseWithUid(uid: String, values: [String: AnyObject]){

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference() // povezava z bazo
    let usersReference = ref.child("users").child(uid)// grajenje drevesne strukture v bazi
    usersReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in

        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("Registration success")
    })
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you're already got an image URL stored in your user credential, why would you want to re-host the image? You can just download the image and keep it cached locally and it's much easier.

Comment: I want the image to be stored in Firebase Storage

Comment: @MikeMcDonald And can you show me how to cache an image ?

Comment: I am confused. Are you saying that there is a racing problem while uploading  or at each login your users profile pic gets uploaded resulting in duplicate copies?

Comment: @Dravidian second... each login users profile pic gets uploaded resulting duplicate copies

Comment: You mean every user that is in your auth section irrespective to google auth , Facebook auth or email/Pass? and even if its just google auth users , its odd..

Comment: The issue is just that the image uploads every single time, which wastes bandwidth, etc. You can easily do a metadata get (to check if an object exists) and then upload if it doesn't, but honestly, there's no reason why you need to re-host the profile image if it's always going to be in the token.

Comment: @MikeMcDonald ok got it, thanks :)